# Swift when clicking on table view cell it says index out of range or goes back to the home screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

For some reason when I click on a table view cell it kicks me out of the app or says the index is out of range. The information is being passed because it is displaying the book titles in the table view cells, not sure why it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated

The segue to connect booksearchview and inroviewcontroller is correct

My view controller for searching for book

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var bookTitleTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var authorTextField: UITextField!

var book: String = ""
var author: String = ""

var bookCoversInfo = [UIImage]()
var titlesInfo = [String]()
var authorsInfo = [String]()
var yearInfo = [String]()
var pagesInfo = [String]()
var starRatingInfo = [UIImage]()
var starRatingCountInfo = [Double]()
var reviewsInfo = [String]()
var descriptionsInfo = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bookTitleTextField.delegate = self
    authorTextField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    bookTitleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    authorTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}

func initializeTextFields() {
    bookTitleTextField.delegate = self
    bookTitleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default

    authorTextField.delegate = self
    authorTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
}

@IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var query = ""

    if let book = bookTitleTextField.text, let author = authorTextField.text {
        query = book
        if (!query.isEmpty) {
            query += "+"
        }
        query += "inauthor\(author)"
    }

    if let book = bookTitleTextField.text {
        query = book
    }

    if let author = authorTextField.text {
        if (!query.isEmpty) {
            query += "+"
        }
        query += "inauthor:\(author)"
    }

    let session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: config)
    }()

    let queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query)]
    let urlComps = NSURLComponents(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?")!
    urlComps.queryItems = queryItems as [URLQueryItem]
    let booksURL = urlComps.url!

    let request = URLRequest(url: booksURL)

 //   let request = URLRequest(url: urlComps.url!)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonData = data {
            if let jsonString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) {
                    let arrayOfTitles = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.title") as? [String]
                    if let items = arrayOfTitles {
                        self.titlesInfo = items
                    }

                    let arrayOfAuthors = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.authors") as? [String]
                    if let itemsA = arrayOfAuthors {
                        self.authorsInfo = itemsA
                    }

              //  let arrayOfYear = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.pageCount") as? [String]
                   let arrayOfPage = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.pageCount") as? [String]
                    if let itemPages = arrayOfPage {
                        self.pagesInfo = itemPages
                    }

                    let arrayOfRatings = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath:    "items.volumeInfo.averageRating") as? [UIImage]
                    if let itemStars = arrayOfRatings {
                        self.starRatingInfo = itemStars
                    }

                    let arrayOfReviews = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.ratingsCount") as? [String]
                    if let itemRating = arrayOfReviews {
                        self.reviewsInfo = itemRating
                    }

                    let arrayOfStarsCount = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath:    "items.volumeInfo.averageRating") as? [Double]
                    if let itemStarsCount = arrayOfStarsCount {
                        self.starRatingCountInfo = itemStarsCount
                    }

                    let arrayOfDescription = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.description") as? [String]
                    if let itemDescription = arrayOfDescription {
                        self.descriptionsInfo = itemDescription
                    }

                    let arrayOfBookCover = (jsonString as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail") as? [UIImage]
                    if let itemCover = arrayOfBookCover {
                        self.bookCoversInfo = itemCover
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "findTitles", sender: self)
                    }
            }
        }
            else {
                print("Error fetching books \(error.debugDescription)")
            }
        }
    task.resume()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    bookTitleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    authorTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "findTitles") {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? BookSearchView {
            destinationVC.bookCoversReady = bookCoversInfo
            destinationVC.booksReady = titlesInfo
            destinationVC.authorsReady = authorsInfo
            destinationVC.yearReady = yearInfo
            destinationVC.pagesReady = pagesInfo
            destinationVC.starRatingReady = starRatingInfo
            destinationVC.starRatingCountReady = starRatingCountInfo
            destinationVC.reviewsReady = reviewsInfo
            destinationVC.descriptionsReady = descriptionsInfo
        }
    }
}

}
```

My book search where table view cells are

```
import UIKit
 import Foundation

 var myIndex = 0

class BookSearchView: UITableViewController {

var bookCoversReady = [UIImage]()
var booksReady = [String]()
var authorsReady = [String]()
var yearReady = [String]()
var pagesReady = [String]()
var starRatingReady = [UIImage]()
var starRatingCountReady = [Double]()
var reviewsReady = [String]()
var descriptionsReady = [String]()

var bookCoversSend: UIImage?
var titleSend: String = ""
var authorsSend: String = ""
var yearSend: String = ""
var pagesSend: String = ""
var starRatingSend: UIImage?
var starRatingCountSend: Double = 0.0
var reviewsSend: String = ""
var descriptionsSend: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return booksReady.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = booksReady[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = authorsReady[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myIndex = indexPath.row
    // bookCoversSend = bookCoversReady[indexPath.row]
         //  titleSend = booksReady[indexPath.row]
       //    authorsSend = authorsReady[indexPath.row]
       //    yearSend = yearReady[indexPath.row]
        //   pagesSend = pagesReady[indexPath.row]
        //   starRatingSend = starRatingReady[indexPath.row]
        //   starRatingCountSend = starRatingCountReady[indexPath.row]
        //   reviewsSend = reviewsReady[indexPath.row]
        //   descriptionsSend = descriptionsReady[indexPath.row]
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookInfo", sender: self)
    }
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "bookInfo") {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? InfoViewController {
            destinationVC.bookCoversDisplay = bookCoversReady
            destinationVC.titlesDisplay = booksReady
            destinationVC.authorsDisplay = authorsReady
            destinationVC.yearDisplay = yearReady
            destinationVC.pagesDisplay = pagesReady
            destinationVC.starRatingDisplay = starRatingReady
            destinationVC.starRatingNumber = starRatingCountReady
            destinationVC.reviewsDisplay = reviewsReady
            destinationVC.descriptionsDisplay = descriptionsReady
        }
    }
}
}
```

My info view controller for displaying book info

```
 import UIKit
import Foundation

class InfoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var bookTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var authorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var bookYear: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var numberOfPages: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var totalReviews: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var bookCoverImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var ratingStars: UIImageView!

  var titlesDisplay = [String]()
var authorsDisplay = [String]()
  var yearDisplay = [String]()
  var pagesDisplay = [String]()
  var starRatingNumber = [Double]()
  var reviewsDisplay = [String]()
  var descriptionsDisplay = [String]()
  var bookCoversDisplay = [UIImage]()
  var starRatingDisplay = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bookCoverImage.image = bookCoversDisplay[myIndex]
    bookTitleLabel.text = titlesDisplay[myIndex]
    authorLabel.text = authorsDisplay[myIndex]
    bookYear.text = yearDisplay[myIndex]
    numberOfPages.text = pagesDisplay[myIndex]
    ratingStars.image = starRatingDisplay[myIndex]
    let starRating = starRatingNumber[myIndex]
    totalReviews.text = reviewsDisplay[myIndex]
    descriptionLabel.text = descriptionsDisplay[myIndex]

    if starRating < 0.5 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "zerostars")
    } else if starRating >= 0.5 && starRating < 1.0 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "halfstar")
    } else if starRating >= 1.0 && starRating < 1.5 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "onestar")
    } else if starRating >= 1.5 && starRating < 2.0 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "onehalfstar")
    } else if starRating >= 2.0 && starRating < 2.5 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "twostars")
    } else if starRating >= 2.5 && starRating < 3.0 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "twohalfstars")
    } else if starRating >= 3.0 && starRating < 3.5 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "threestars")
    } else if starRating >= 3.5 && starRating < 4.0 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "threehalfstars")
    } else if starRating >= 4.0 && starRating < 4.5 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "fourstars")
    } else if starRating >= 4.5 && starRating < 5.0 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "fourhalfstars")
    } else if starRating == 5.0 {
        ratingStars.image = UIImage(named: "fivestars")
    }

   //  bookCoverImage.image = bookCoversDisplay
  //   bookTitleLabel.text = titlesDisplay
  //   authorLabel.text = authorsDisplay
  //   bookYear.text = yearDisplay
  //   numberOfPages.text = pagesDisplay
  //   ratingStars.image = starRatingDisplay
  //   totalReviews.text = reviewsDisplay
  //   descriptionLabel.text = descriptionsDisplay

}
}
```

Comment: Issue may be in InfoViewController  viewDidLoad, Make sure myIndex 
 is less than array count.

Comment: I checked for each array count but when I test, it just displays the normal screen before edits are made.

Answer (score 0):

In your BookSearchView, i think you are returning 2 sections for showing two sections in tableview where one will show the books contents and the another will show author contents.
If this is case,

You need to return numberOfRowsInSection conditionally like this

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
      case 0: return booksReady.count
      case 1: return authorsReady.count
      default: return 0
  }
```

you are getting index out of range error because you are trying to access authorsready index which is not defined yet in numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: That made my titles not repeat in the table view cells. When I click a tableview cell it just goes back to the home screen still.

Comment: The other arrays besides title and description are still at 0

Answer (score 0):

If you change the author names code as below it will work. Because author names are coming as Array of Array.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = booksReady[indexPath.row] as? String
        var authorNames = authorsReady[0] as! [Any]
        let authorNamesStr = authorNames[indexPath.row] as! [Any]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = authorNamesStr[0] as? String
        return cell
    }
```